# Issue with compare dates in where clause in dbml linq

Tags: c#, linq

I'm using DBML to linq search in my application. I Designed advanced search queries with `DynamicLibrary.cs` related to this article:
[Dynamic query with Linq](http://pranayamr.blogspot.com/2011/04/dynamic-query-with-linq.html)
So I Create a dbml and use it for my advanced linq search without extra connecting to the database. I don't have any problem with datatypes except `date` datatype.

This is my `whereClause()` function that I use it.

```
private string whereClause()
{
    string strWhere = string.Empty;
    if (rbvalveStreet.Checked)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(valveStreet.Text))
        {
            strWhere += " valveStreet.Contains(\"" + valveStreet.Text + "\") AND ";
        }
    }

    if (rbhealth.Checked)
    {
        strWhere += " health = " + health.SelectedIndex.ToString() + " AND ";
    }
    if (rbleak.Checked)
    {
        strWhere += " leak = " + leak.SelectedIndex.ToString() + " AND ";
    }
    if (chbDateRange.Checked)
    {
        string fromDate = clsEasy.makeDate8((DateTime)dtsFrom.Value); //ex: 2018/07/30
        string toDate = clsEasy.makeDate8((DateTime)dtsTo.Value); //ex: 2018/08/05
        strWhere += " washdate >= " + fromDate + "  && washdate <= "+ toDate + " AND ";
    }
    string[] remove = { " AND " };
    foreach (string item in remove)
    {
        if (strWhere.EndsWith(item))
        {
            strWhere = strWhere.Substring(0, strWhere.LastIndexOf(item));
            break; //only allow one match at most
        }
    }

    return strWhere;
}
```

I want add to `strWhere` a linq query with search between to dates when chbDateRange is Checked. But I get this error: 
[image: error 1[2]]

Also `washdate` column's datatype is `Date` and I try the following code either:

```
DateTime fromDate =  DateTime.Parse(clsEasy.makeDate8((DateTime)dtsFrom.Value));
DateTime toDate = DateTime.Parse(clsEasy.makeDate8((DateTime)dtsTo.Value));
strWhere += " washdate >= " + fromDate + "  && washdate <= "+ toDate + " AND ";
```

and get this another error:
[image: error 2]

I'm sure a data type conflict occurred here. please Help me to resolve this problem. Thanks.

**Edited**:

```
clsEasy.makeDate8((DateTime)dtsFrom.Value) retrun date as string for example "2018/07/30"
```

**Edited 2:**

This is how I use whereClause() for Linq DBML:

```
private void btnFind_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string wClause = this.whereClause();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(wClause))
        {
            string address = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=valveManagement2018;Integrated Security=True";
            dgv.DataSource = null;
            refreshData();
            contextLinqDataContext cxt = new contextLinqDataContext(address);
            var query = cxt.tblValveExpirations
                        .Where(wClause);
            _dt = null;
            _dt = LINQToDataTable(query);
            refreshForm();
            countRows();
        }
        else
        {
            refreshData();
            refreshForm();
            countRows();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You don't need to create a SQL string to add filters dynamically. You can chain multiple `.Where()` calls to create the equivalent of `Condition1 && Condition2 && Condition3)`

Comment: please write your code to show me how can I do?

Comment: I think the error is due to following : (DateTime)dtsFrom.Value  You can't cast an integer to a DateTime.

Comment: I explained (DateTime)dtsFrom.Value in my post

Comment: @RezaPaidar DateTime is a binary value, it has no format. Using a localized string like `YYYY/MM/DD` guarantees conversion errors. Even if you *have* to use a string, the only unambiguous date format is the unseparated `YYYYMMDD` format. In this case though, you don't need it

Comment: @RezaPaidar once you clean up the code you'll see that you are passing the *combobox indexes* as parameters to the query. I suspect you wanted to pass the *values* instead.

Comment: @ Panagiotis Kanavos Thanks for your tip but I don't have any problem with other section of codes. combobox indexes are works well. I just problem with date linq query.

Comment: @RezaPaidar you do have a problem. You are passing a math expression to the server, not a date. If the rest of the code is like this it's essentially dynamic sql and thus vulnerable to all related problems: SQL injection, localized type conversions.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create a SQL string to add filters dynamically. You can chain multiple .Where() calls to create the equivalent of `(Condition1 && Condition2 && Condition3)`.

Assuming the original query is stored in a variable called `query` you could write something like this :

```
IQueryable<MyEntity> query = ....;

if (rbvalveStreet.Checked && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(valveStreet.Text))
{
    var searchText=valveStreet.Text;
    query=query.Where(item=>item.valveStreet.Contains(searchText);
}
if (rbhealth.Checked)
{
    //Do we really want the *indexes*?
    //SHouldn't this be the selected text/value?
    var healthIdx=health.SelectedIndex;
    query = query.Where(itme=>item.health = healthIdx);
}
if (rbleak.Checked)
{
    var leakIdx=leak.SelectedIndex;
    query = query.Where(item=>item.leak = leakIdx);
}
if (chbDateRange.Checked)
{
    //No need to cast if this is a DateTimePicker control
    DateTime fromDate = dtsFrom.Value; 
    DateTime toDate = dtsTo.Value; 

    query = query.Where(item=> item.washdate >=fromDate
                            && item.washdate<= toDate)
}
```

The final `query` will have all specified criteria combined with an `AND` operator

Comment: Please read http://pranayamr.blogspot.com/2011/04/dynamic-query-with-linq.html article. Your method is not suitable for my code. and I don't have a problem with the method. I just get error with date value even I use DateTime.Now.

Comment: @RezaPaidar I know what "Dynamic LINQ" is and it's not needed in many cases. In this case converting dates to strings *is* the problem. LINQ ensures you can't mix up different types. With strings, you'll have to check the final SQL query to find out what whent wrong.

Comment: @RezaPaidar in this case you are using a *localized* string to generate a *sql string*. I suspect you'll find the actual SQL query is `washdate >= 2018/07/30`. That's a math expression, not a date string. Specifically your query is equivalent to `washdate >= 9`

Comment: Yes I think you exactly right but what's the correct format for linq propuse

Comment: I already posted it. There's a very good reason "Dynamic LINQ" isnt' used any more. It was never a feature or library. The real source is an article posted by Scott Guthrie [back in 2008](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library). "Dynamic LINQ" was just a sample. In any case I doubt the library allows raw values to appear in the query like this. How did you execute that string? Or is the exception thrown by the library itself because the string is invalid?

Comment: I added the method How did I execute that string