# Create custom Queryable in LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, linq

I want to build an advanced search with Linq to SQL.
I already accomplished my purpose with `Dynamic query with Linq` using this [article](http://pranayamr.blogspot.com/2011/04/dynamic-query-with-linq.html), but `DynamicLibrary` has a specific problem with some datatype like dates. So it ***can not*** translate date values to LINQ and throw an error.
I already ask this problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51597447/issue-with-compare-dates-in-where-clause-in-dbml-linq?noredirect=1#comment90162716_51597657) and didn't get answered. 
So I started changing my method to use Queryable.
This is what I want to do with Queryable:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LinqTestDataContext ctx = new LinqTestDataContext("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=valveManagement2018;Integrated Security=True");
        if (rbvalveStreet.Checked)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(valveStreet.Text))
            {
                var qry1 = Queryable.Select(Queryable.Where(
                         ctx.valves, p => p.valveStreet.Contains(valveStreet.Text)), p => new { p.valveId, p.aTId,p.typeId, p.valveStreet });
            }
        }
        if (rbtypeId.Checked)
        {
                var qry2 = Queryable.Select(Queryable.Where(
            ctx.valves, p => p.typeId == cbTypeId.selectedIndex), p => new { p.valveId, p.aTId, p.typeId,p.valveStreet });
        }

        var qryFinal = qry1.Concat(qry2);

        dgv.DataSource = qryFinal;
    }
```

But the problem is here, Concat act Like `OR` Operand and the result is
 `qry1 OR qry2`, But I want to get something Like `AND` Operand somthing Like `qry1 AND qry2`.
So how can I handle this problem or any safe way exist to handle custom where in linq to sql?

Comment: I can't see the need for custom in this code. Plain Linq To SQL would do (and it implements as "and" rather than "or"). Maybe you should also check Joseph Albahari's predicateBuilder.

Comment: There is an answer on your other question that provides quite a nice explanation of how to do this? ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not custom but plain Linq To SQL:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LinqTestDataContext ctx = new LinqTestDataContext("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=valveManagement2018;Integrated Security=True");
        var data = ctx.valves.AsQueryable();

        if (rbvalveStreet.Checked)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(valveStreet.Text))
            {
               data = data.Where(p => p.valveStreet.Contains(valveStreet.Text));
            }
        }
        if (rbtypeId.Checked)
        {
               data = data.Where(p => p.typeId == cbTypeId.selectedIndex);
        }

        var qryFinal = data.Select( p => new { p.valveId, p.aTId, p.typeId,p.valveStreet });

        dgv.DataSource = qryFinal.ToList();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work with Linq2Sql and is much simpler to follow:

```
LinqTestDataContext ctx = new LinqTestDataContext("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=valveManagement2018;Integrated Security=True");

bool includeValveStreet = rbvalveStreet.Checked,
     includeTypeId = rbtypeId.Checked;

dgv.DataSource = ctx.valves.Where(p => (includeValveStreet && p.valveStreet.Contains(valveStreet.Text))
                                    || (includeTypeId && p.typeId == cbTypeId.selectedIndex)))
                            .Select(p => new { p.valveId, p.aTId,p.typeId, p.valveStreet })
                            .ToList();
```